# Accessing terminal and doing operations on another Linux installation and partition of the same hard disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have linux A on partition A and linux B on partition B of the same hard disk. Now when I enter in linux A.

Is it possible from terminal on linux A to remove and install some drivers on linux B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by applying two approaches:

**First:**

If your driver is delivered by repository or some install script (like NVidia drivers) you can mount partition B of linux B and mount `proc`, `sys`, `dev`:

```
# mount -t proc proc /mount/point/partition/B/proc
# mount -t sysfs sysfs /mount/point/partition/B/sys
# mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /mount/point/partition/B/dev
```

Then `chroot` to `/mount/point/partition/B`:

```
# chroot /mount/point/partition/B/
```

Now you are working in linux B like you are booted in linux B. You can use repository commands (`yum`, `apt` ...) and others.

**!!!But you need to remember!!!**

Loaded kernel of linux A may be different from kernel on linux B so all utilities that use kernel version as parameter by default (`dkms`, initramfs tools (`dracut`, `mkinitrd` ...), some installation scripts) will fail. So you need to specify kernel version of linux B as parameter for these utilities!

**Second:**

Mount partition B of linux B and remove drivers (modules) in this partition by hand doing `rm /mount/point/partition/B/lib/modules/needed_kernel_version_of_linux_B/module/path/module.ko`. Also you may want to clean up **modprobe** or/and **udev** rules. This approach isn't clean and suited if you really know what you are doing (how your driver organised and how it influences on linux B).

---

Small Example:

In linux A type `lsblk` command. This give you imagine of partitions which are used and mounted in linux A and partitions with empty mountpoint. If you haven't attached removable devices, then all partitions with empty mountpoint relate to linux B. Create directories in which you will mount partitions of linux B and mount it:

Simple case without LVM and others:

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    12G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0   150G  0 part  /
└─sda3   8:3    0  61.6G  0 part
```

Device `sda3` isn't mounted so it relay to linux B.

Create `/mnt/sda3` directory and mount root of linux B:

```
# mkdir /mnt/sda3
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3
```

Prepare for `chroot`:

```
# mount -t proc proc /mnt/sda3/proc
# mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/sda3/sys
# mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /mnt/sda3/dev
```

`chroot`:

```
# chroot /dev/sda3
```

Now, you are in linux B!

Comment: OK, in order to follow this answer, would you mind adding mounting linux B from linux A at the beginnning for future reference. Bol6oe spasibo, Yurij

Comment: @joyag95613 You are welcome! I've added small example.